# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined - callback function axios

Tags: reactjs, callback

Utils.js

This is my function to handle requests and I want to work the response with callback.

```
 static Request(data, callback) {

        const method = data[0] || "";
        const url = data[1] || "";
        const param = data[2] || "";
        const headers = data[3] || "";

        if (method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
            var data = {
                url: url,
                method: method.toLowerCase(),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    param
                }
            };

            if (headers) {
                data.headers = {
                    headers
                };
            }

            axios(data).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        } else if (method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {
            axios.get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data);
                    callback(response.data);
                    return (response.data);
                })
        } else {
            console.log("Undefined");
        }
    }
```

This is how I try to get the response from the callback. (different file)

```
handleClick() {
    Utils.Request(['get', 'www.URL.com'],
      function Response(data) {
        this.state({ response: data.msg })
      })
  }
```

Then in a button

```
  button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Teste</button
```

The error I get is **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined**

What im doing wrong?

Full component here. Its a new fresh component..

```
export default class Discover extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { itemArray: [], response: null };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }


  handleClick() {
    Utils.Request(['get', 'url'],
      function Response(data) {
        this.setState({ response: data.msg })
      })
  }

  render() {

    return <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => { console.log(this.state.response) }}>Click</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Teste</button>

    </React.Fragment>;
  }
}
```

Comment: the error seems to be coming from your component file. can you verify that ? exactly where you are getting this error ?

Comment: The erros comes from:  this.state({ response: data.msg }) @MohammadFaisal

Comment: As i expected. Can you share your full component code ?  so that we can see whats wrong there ?

Comment: Its a new fresh component, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Check my answer and see if it helps

Comment: If I don't want to use state how can I use it with a new function? I mean save the response and work with it on a function

Comment: `Response` also needs to be bound to `this` or be changed into an arrow function.

Comment: Can you tell me how? Im really new on this.. thanks @BrianThompson

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks Brian!!!

Comment: `(data) => { this.setState({ response: data.msg }) })`